# Data structure to represent Teams and Players

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

There is a `Team` object , that contains list of players `List<Players>`. All teams need to be stored in a `Teams` collection.

**Conditions:**

1. If a new player need to be added to a particular team , that particular team is  retrieved from `Teams` and `Player` need to be added to  `Players` list of that team
2. Each `Team` object in the collection `Teams` need to be unique based on the `team name`
3. `Team` objects in the collection need to be sorted based on `team name`.

**Considerations:**

In this scenario when I use `List<Team>` , I can achieve 1, 3 . But uniqueness cannot be satisfied.

If I use `TreeSet<Team>` 2,3 can be achieved. But as there is no `get` method on TreeSet , a particular team cannot be selected

So I ended up using `TreeMap<teamName,Team>`. This makes all 1,2,3 possible. But I think it's not the good way to do it

Which Data Structure is ideal for this use case? Preferably form Java collections.

Comment: Why not one TreeMap player -> team and one TreeSet team -> players? Often multiple simple data-structures together are more efficient. Build an extra class holding these and which offers an interface to change these coherently.

Comment: `But I think it's not the good way to do it` Why?

Comment: TreeMap sounds fine for this usecase. Why don't you like it?

Comment: My thinking is when ever I want  do operations on this `TreeMap` , I need to handle  inserting both `team name` along with the `Team`.

Comment: Uniqueness can be satisfied with a `List` by overriding `equals()` to evaluate based on team name, and then using `contains` prior to insert. In addition, you can create a method `get(String teamName)` in your class that will search the List.

Comment: @mc20 You don't directly expose your `TreeMap`. Just use it internally in `Teams` class. Then add a `getByName(..)` and a `save(Team team)`

Comment: @AminJ That sounds good. I was passing both `TeamName` and `Team` object to the class. Instead I can just pass `Team` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize your TreeSet if you wish. However, if you're going to utilize the Set interface you can use remove(object o) instead of get. You'll remove the object, make your modifications, then add it back into the set.

Answer (score 0):

I think extending (i.e. creating a subclass from) [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or LinkedList and overriding the set(), add(), addAll(), remove(), and removeRange() methods in such way that they ensure the uniqueness and sortedness conditions (invariants) would be a very clean design. You can also implement a binary search method in your class to quickly find a team with a given name.

ArrayList is a better choice to base your class on, if you aren't going to add or remove teams too frequently. ArrayList would give you O(n) insertion and removal, but O(log n) cost for element access and ensuring uniqueness if you use binary search (where n is the number of elements in the array).

See the [generics tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html) for subclassing generics.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a Guava's [MultiMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiMap.html)? More precisely, a [SetMultimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap.html). Specifically, a [SortedSetMultimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/SortedSetMultimap.html). Even more specifically, its [TreeMultimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html) implementation (1).

Explanations:

- In a `MultiMap`, a `Key` points not to a *single value*, but rather to a `Collection` of values.
  This means you can bind to a single `Team` key a collection of several `Player` values, so that's **Req1** solved.
- In a `SetMultiMap`, the `Key`s are unique.
  This gets your **Req2** solved.
- In a `SortedSetMultimap`, the `Values`s are also sorted.
  While you don't specifically care for this, it's nice to have.
- In a `TreeMultimap`, The `Key`set *and* each of their `Values` collections are Sorted.
  This gets your **Req3** sorted *(See what I did there?)*

Usage:

```
TreeMultimap<Team, Player> ownership = new TreeMultimap<Team, Player>();
ownership.put(team1, playerA);
ownership.put(team1, playerB);
ownership.put(team2, playerC);
Collection<Player> playersOfTeamA = ownership.get(team1); // contains playerA, playerB
SortedSet<Team> allTeams = ownership.keySet(); // contains team1, team2
```

---

Gothas:

- Remember to set `equals` and `hashCode` correctly on your `Team` object to use its `name`.
  Alternatively, you could use the static `create(Comparator<? super K> keyComparator, Comparator<? super V> valueComparator)` which provides a purpose-built comparison if you do not wish to change the natural ordering of Team. (use [Ordering.natural()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#natural()) for the Player comparator to keep its natural ordering - another nice Guava thing). In any case, make sure it is compatible with `equals`!
- MultiMaps are not Maps because `put`ing a new value to a key does **not** remove the previously held value (that's the whole point), so make sure you understand it. (for instance it still hold that you cannot put a key-value pair twice...)

---

(1): I am unsure wether SortedSetMultimap is sufficient. In its Javadoc, it states the Values are sorted, but nothing is said of the keys. Does anyone know any better?

(2) I assure you, I'm not affiliated to Guava in any way. I just find it awesome!